# Warning in system("sh ./configure.win") : 'sh' not found

Tags: r, rodbc

I am trying to install the package "RODBC" on my laptop.
However, I get the following error when trying to install the package.[image]

I have googled around a bit, but couldnt find anything particularly helpful for my case.

The only thing I could find was that currently the package is only applicable for R-versions greater than 4.0. However, I also installed this package a few weeks ago on another laptop (with a version lower than 4.0), and I did manage to install the package on that laptop.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Some packages need [RTools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to be installed on Windows first. This seems to be your case as the first red line says: `RTools (...) is not currently installed`.

Visit the official site https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and install RTools first. It comes with a number of tools that are needed to compile packages on Windows.

Comment: Hello, I have installed RTools, and tried to install an earlier version of the package using the line `install_version("RODBC", version = "1.3-16", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")`. However, during the installation I still get a pop-up message which asks me to install "additional build tools".

Comment: @matthew Hm, that's strange. Your error message says that you are installing from source, maybe running binary version `install.packages("RODBC", type = "binary")` could help. Or - do you have appropriate RTools version to your R version? (See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html).) And _ODBC Driver Manager_ is required to install RODBC, according to the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf)...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In the screenshot above, I tried to install an earlier version of the RODBC package using `install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RODBC/RODBC_1.3-16.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")`. However, trying your line of code (and replacing RODBC with my url link) didnt work either. I got the following warning "cannot open compressed file "RODBC_1.3-16.tar.gz/DESCRIPTION", probable reason "No such file or directory""

Comment: @matthew Well, I thought something different: run either `install.packages("RODBC", type = "binary", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")` (to install latest compatible version) or  `install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/RODBC_1.3-16.zip", type = "binary", repos = NULL)` (to install that version from binary). Note that you _have to_ use only `.zip` binary when installing on Windows.